# How can a function that takes a record as an argument take the result of a query as a parameter (without rewriting the name of all the columns)?

Tags: oracle

I didn't find a way to do that.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d17c9f9a15fd32367c2fad58d48ac04c

```
CREATE TYPE arguments_r IS  OBJECT
(
    q    integer,
    b            INTEGER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f (p IN arguments_r)
    RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END;

with a(a1,a2) as (select 1 , 2 from dual) 
select f(arguments_r(a.* ))  from a;
```

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

I could select the name of all column (like what propose Connor McDonald) but I don't want to do that.

I've a table (my_table) with a lot a columns and I will use a lot of this columns in my function. The type of the argument of my function is my_table%ROWTYPE.

Comment: Depending on the actual problem you are trying to solve, you could fetch the data from your table into a local variable of type `my_table%rowtype` and then pass that local variable to your function.  That would involve using PL/SQL for your function call rather than pure SQL but I don't know if that is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're close - you just to pass the object from the query columns

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE arguments_r IS  OBJECT
  2  (
  3      q    integer,
  4      b            INTEGER
  5  );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f (p IN arguments_r)
  2      RETURN INTEGER
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5      RETURN 1;
  6  END;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> with a as
  2    (select 1 x, 2 y from dual)
  3  select f(arguments_r(x,y)) from a;

F(ARGUMENTS_R(X,Y))
-------------------
                  1
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for helping me. Your solution is working, but I don't want to write the name of the columns. I edit my question to explained why